# I'm trying to sum all the rows of a single column in a Data extension and then divide that sum by the total rows so I can get the average

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

This is what I've written so far but I keep getting errors on the summing part. Eventually with this I'll have to sum a bunch of multiple fields and divide because I need to display the averages of multiple fields.

```
SET @rows = LookupOrderedRows('ent.DataExtesion', 0, 'fieldToSum asc', 'Brandname', @Brandname)
SET @rowCount = RowCount(@rows)

FOR @i = 1 TO @rowCount DO
    SET @rowTotal = Row(@rows,@i)
    SET @Sum = Field(@row, 'fieldToSum')
    SET @total = add(@total, @Sum)

NEXT @i
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an AMPscript math example:

```ampscript
%%[

set @BrandName = "whee"
SET @rows = LookupOrderedRows("QCvFyfPr", 0, "fieldToSum", "BrandName", @BrandName)
SET @rowCount = RowCount(@rows)
output(concat("rowCount: ", @rowCount, "<hr>"))
set @total = 0

FOR @i = 1 TO @rowCount DO

    SET @row = Row(@rows, @i)
    SET @fieldToSum = Field(@row, "fieldToSum")
    SET @total = add(@total, @fieldToSum)
    output(concat("<br>fieldToSum: ", @fieldToSum))


NEXT @i

output(concat("<hr>total: ", @total))
set @average = iif(@rowCount > 0, divide(@rowCount, @total), 0)
output(concat("<hr>average: ", @average))


]%%
```

Try it yourself: [mcsnippet](https://mcsnippets.herokuapp.com/s/6KZgCrii)

**Reference**

- [lookuporderedrows](https://ampscript.guide/lookuporderedrows)
- [add](https://ampscript.guide/add)
- [iif](https://ampscript.guide/iif)
- [divide](https://ampscript.guide/divide)

Comment: Hi Adam thank you for your help. Is there a way to divide only on the rows that have greater than 0?

Comment: Not sure what you mean.   The `set @average = iif(@rowCount > 0, divide(@rowCount, @total), 0)` ensures you're not dividing by zero.